# Hibernate JPA problem accessing a ManyToMany relationship: Invalid identifier

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with a ManyToMany relationship in Java.
The first entity is this one:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="MODULOCONTROL")
 public class ModuloControl extends Auditable<Integer> {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="MODULOCONTROL_SEQ")
      @SequenceGenerator(name="MODULOCONTROL_SEQ", sequenceName="MODULOCONTROL_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize=2)
      private Integer id;

      /* Other fields */

      @JoinTable(
           name = "MODULOCONTROL_FF",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IDMODULOCONTROL", nullable = false),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="IDFUNFUND", nullable = false)
      )
      @ManyToMany
      private List<FuncionFundamental> funFund=new ArrayList<FuncionFundamental>();

     /* getters & setters */

 }
```

The second entity is this one:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL")
 public class FuncionFundamental extends BaseEntity<Integer>{      

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL_SEQ")
      @SequenceGenerator(name="FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL_SEQ", sequenceName="FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize=2)
      @Column(name="ID")
      private Integer id;

        /* Other fields */     

      @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "funFund")
      private List<ModuloControl> modulosControl;

      /* getters & setters */

  }
```

And this is the code to retrieve the list of FuncionFundamental of ModuloControl (ModuloControl is successfully retrieved)

```
 @Transactional(readOnly=true)
 public ModuloControl recuperarModuloControl(Long id, Context context) throws ServiceException {
      try {
           ModuloControl mc1 = dao.recuperarModuloControl(id, context);
           mc1.getFunFund().size();
           /* ... */
           return mc1;
      }catch (DaoException e){
           throw new ServiceException(e);
      }

 }
```

When I try to get the FuncionFundamental's list I get this error (invalid identifier):

```
nov 12, 2020 12:42:42 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
ADVERTENCIA: SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
<12-nov-2020 12H42' CET> <Warning> <org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter> <BEA-000000> <SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000>
nov 12, 2020 12:42:42 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
GRAVE: ORA-00904: "FUNFUND0_"."IDFUNFUND": identificador no válido

<12-nov-2020 12H42' CET> <Error> <org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter> <BEA-000000> <ORA-00904: "FUNFUND0_"."IDFUNFUND": identificador no válido
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDITED:
These are my create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL (
    ID NUMBER(10,0), 
    DESCRIPCION VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(25 CHAR)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IVDCGDR2"."PK_FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL" ON "IVDCGDR2"."FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL" ("ID");
ALTER TABLE "IVDCGDR2"."FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL" PRIMARY KEY ("ID");


CREATE TABLE MODULOCONTROL_FF (
    
    IDMODULOCONTROL NUMBER(10,0),
    IDFUNFUND NUMBER (10,0)
    
);
```

And the ModuloControl table was created before. This is the SQL from SQLDEVELOPER:

```
CREATE TABLE "IVDCGDR2"."MODULOCONTROL" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ACTIVO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FINVIGENCIA" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "INICIOVIGENCIA" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "USUARIOVIGENCIA" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "CODPERIODICITAT" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "CODTIPUSMODULCONTROL" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "DESCNIVELORGD" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "DESCNIVELORGMC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "DESCPERIODICITAT" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "DESCTIPUSMC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "DESCTIPUSORGD" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "DESCTIPUSORGMC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "DESCRIPCION" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "NIVELORGANIGRAMADESVIACION" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "NIVELORGANIGRAMAMODULOCONTROL" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "TIPUSORGANIGRAMADESVIACION" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "TIPUSORGANIGRAMAMODULOCONTROL" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "TOLERANCIA" VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR), 
    "IDPROYECTO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "IDRIESGO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FUNCIONMODULOCONTROL" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FUNCIONDESVIACION" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "PCTAPLICACIONAUTOVALORADA" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "FECHAVALORACION" DATE, 
    "DESCRIPCIONCONTROL" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "PCTAPLICACIONAUTOVALANT" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "EVIDENCIACONSERVAR" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ADJUNTAREVIDENCIA" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N', 
    "EVIDENCIAADJUNTADA" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N', 
    "MODULOSCIIF" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "CERTIFICADOCBK" NUMBER(10,0), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TS_SCHGDR_DAT"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK3CADC607A58E0A13" FOREIGN KEY ("IDPROYECTO")
      REFERENCES "IVDCGDR2"."PROYECTO" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK3CADC607C53D07E3" FOREIGN KEY ("IDRIESGO")
      REFERENCES "IVDCGDR2"."RIESGO" ("ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TS_SCHGDR_DAT" ;
```

Edited 2:
These are BaseEntity class and Auditable class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3441103420533446056L;  
    
    /**
     * @return Objeto cuyos atributos identifican a la entidad
     */
    public abstract T getId();
    public abstract void setId(T id);

}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Auditable<T> extends BaseEntity<T> {

    @Column(length=1)
    private Integer activo;
    private Date inicioVigencia;
    private Date finVigencia;   
    private String usuarioVigencia;

    
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        //Setear usuarios, activo a true, etc.
        inicioVigencia = new Date();
        activo = 1;
        UserDetails user = null;
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext() != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            user = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            usuarioVigencia = user.getUsername();
        }
    }
    
    @PreUpdate()
    public void antesdeupdatear() {
        UserDetails user = null;
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext() != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            user = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            usuarioVigencia = user.getUsername();
        }
    }
    
    public Integer getActivo() {
        return activo;
    }
    public void setActivo(Integer activo) {
        this.activo = activo;
    }
    public Date getFinVigencia() {
        return finVigencia;
    }
    public void setFinVigencia(Date finVigencia) {
        this.finVigencia = finVigencia;
    }
    public Date getInicioVigencia() {
        return inicioVigencia;
    }
    public void setInicioVigencia(Date inicioVigencia) {
        this.inicioVigencia = inicioVigencia;
    }
    public String getUsuarioVigencia() {
        return usuarioVigencia;
    }
    public void setUsuarioVigencia(String usuarioVigencia) {
        this.usuarioVigencia = usuarioVigencia;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you have the column `IDFUNFUND` in the table `MODULOCONTROL_FF`?

Comment: No, I don't have this column.

Comment: So, as result you have `ORA-00904: "FUNFUND0_"."IDFUNFUND": identificador no válido`

Comment: Please show ER diagram of related part your domain model.

Comment: In a manyToMany relationship it supposes that this column is the "id" column from the entity. I think I don't need a new column called IDFUNDFUND

Comment: According to your mapping you should have a join table `MODULOCONTROL_FF` that has foreign key `IDMODULOCONTROL` to the `MODULOCONTROL` table and foreign key `IDFUNFUND` to the `FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL` table

Comment: This is my create table for the join table:

Comment: CREATE TABLE MODULOCONTROL_FF (
 
 IDMODULOCONTROL NUMBER(10,0),
 IDFUNFUND NUMBER (10,0)
 
);

Comment: Could you please show the `BaseEntity<Integer>` and `Auditable<Integer>` classes?

Comment: To be honest , your mapping looks valid, and it looks like the mentioned error belong to some other entity. Do you have a table / entity named something like `FUNFUND` ?

Comment: @SternK no, The only table called FunFund is this one.

Comment: You can enable the following properties: `hibernate.show_sql=true`, `hibernate.use_sql_comments=true` and `hibernate.format_sql=true` and then see what exactly hql / jpql lead to the error.

Comment: This is the result. The error is exactly the same above. Hibernate: 
    /* load collection com.segurcaixa.gdr.model.entity.ModuloControl.funFund */ select
        funfund0_.IDMODULOCONTROL as IDMODULO1_10_1_,
        funfund0_.IDFUNFUND as IDFUNFUND1_,
        funcionfun1_.ID as ID37_0_,
        funcionfun1_.descripcion as descripc2_37_0_,
        funcionfun1_.nombre as nombre37_0_ 
    from
        MODULOCONTROL_FF funfund0_ 
    inner join
        FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL funcionfun1_ 
            on funfund0_.IDFUNFUND=funcionfun1_.ID 
    where
        funfund0_.IDMODULOCONTROL=?

Comment: I tested your mapping and it works for me. Did you create `MODULOCONTROL_FF` and `FUNCIONFUNDAMENTAL` tables for the same schema `IVDCGDR2`? Do you use the same user in the `hibernate.connection.username` ?

Comment: Thank you @Sternk! It was a permission problem!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
It was a permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the intermediate table, as the different fields are called than in the related tables, you have to specify the mapping of the columns as follows:

```
@JoinTable(
     name = "MODULOCONTROL_FF",
     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IDMODULOCONTROL", referencedColumnName="ID" nullable = false),
     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="IDFUNFUND", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable = false)
)
```

If referencedColumnName is not specified implicitly it takes the same value.

Comment: Thank you JLarar(), but I've tried it and it doesn't work. The error is the same.

Comment: Based on the comments to your question, you have not modeled the relationship well in the database. You should have a MODULOCONTROL (ID, ...) table, another FUNCTIONFUNDAMENTAL (ID, ...) table and an intermediate table that relates them in N mode: M MODULOCONTROL_FF (IDMODULOCONTROL, IDFUNFUND), if you don't have that model, it's not a ManyToMany or N: M relation

Comment: @JLazar0 Actually, we do not need to specify `referencedColumnName` if this is a primary key of the referred entity.

Comment: I've edited the question with the create tables, if you need to see them. Thank you

Comment: The mapping that I propose is correct if the corresponding FKs exist, if the FKs do not exist you should not model the relationship in the entity, you should do a cross join or something like that in the query. The entities must be a true reflection of each table in the model

Comment: Do you mean that I've to create the foreign keys in SQL for the intermediate table?